# How to get active directory users with logon workstation in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am writing a code for get all active directory user details with `System.DirectoryServices` but
i didn't find a way to get **logon workstation** (LogOnTo field) of each user.

Is there any way to get users workstation name?
thank you for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `System.DirectoryServices` you can user LDAP Filter `(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person))`  to get AD Account Details
and you can try  the folowing for get user workstation's name:

```
 DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = ADProvider.createDirectoryEntry(_Domain.DomainName, _Domain.DomainController, _Domain.Username, _Domain.Password, _targetOU);
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection, "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person))", null, SearchScope.OneLevel);
                SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();
                if (results != null)
                {
                   
                    foreach (SearchResult sr in results)
                    {
                       sr.Properties["userworkstations"][0].ToString();
                    }
                }
```